# JAXB: How to Marshal And Recover Processing Instructions From Original Document?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, processing-instruction

I have a manager that wants to replace their XML java solution with plain JaxB.  Once I Marshal, the XML doesn't come out looking like it went in, and (to my knowledge) I haven't made any changes to it. I could be wrong, perhaps I'm not creating the JAXBContext correctly, but right now it seems like JaxB itself is making changes.

One of the central issues is that JaxB is stripping out the processing instructions from the original document.  Processing instructions are crucial to our business.  We use them for tracking text changes to our documents (things added and removed), and for recording the history of "sections" of text (when the whole thing was first created and where from).  These processing instructions can be at various level of the document, surrounding plain text and nodes.  Without this information the document would be meaningless to our customers.

Is there some way to preserve these processing instructions from the original document when unmarshaling and marshaling?  I've seen people talking on stackoverflow about ADDING processing instructions during marshaling, but I don't see any questions that seem to have an answer on how to preserve EXISTING processing instructions from the original document, and I see nothing on the net.  I've looked into using an XMLAdaptor and XMLStreamReader but I reached a dead-end.  They both seem like solutions geared toward adding PIs, not preserving them.  But I can't rule out that perhaps I am using them wrong.

```
public class JAXBParser {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MeasureDocType.class);

    MeasureDocType mType = unmarshall("C:/Workspace/XCAMeasureParser -     JAXB/processPlace/2018/20170SB__004798AMD.xca", context);
    String measureText = marshal(context, mType);
    System.out.println(measureText);
  }

  public static MeasureDocType unmarshall (String anXmlFileName, JAXBContext context) throws Exception {

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(anXmlFileName));

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<MeasureDocType> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, MeasureDocType.class);

    return root.getValue();

  }

  public static String marshal(JAXBContext pContext, Object pObject) throws JAXBException {

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller();

    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

    if (pObject instanceof MeasureDocType) {
      MeasureDocType measureDocType = (MeasureDocType) pObject;
      ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
      JAXBElement<MeasureDocType> jaxElement = objectFactory.createMeasureDoc(measureDocType);
      marshaller.marshal(jaxElement, sw);
    }

    return sw.toString();
  }

}
```